# I lost the main screen/menu of blender

Tags: interface

I'm new at blender, I just lost the main window with blender logo/file/edit/render/window/help

I only have a small screen with 3D view or timeline for example... I don't know how to get the original interface back.

If I open a new file, it comes back, but if I open the one that have a problem, the main interface don't come back.

The image is the only interface I can get.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Hello what does it give if you press Ctrl Spacebar?

Comment: or ctrl alt spacebar

Comment: If that does not work, go to file (ALT) > default > Load factory settings

Comment: This view can be opened with Window -> New Window, but I'm not sure how it can exist independent of the Main Window.  Is the main window minimized or hidden from view?

Answer (score 1):

The solution summarized from the comments is:

It works with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>